# CodePush React Native Throws an Error on versionName

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

I have set up `env` variables for my Android and iOS apps to retrieve the information like `versionName` and `versionCode` (this is on Android, similar on iOS). It looks something like this for dev:

```
API_URL=https://linkToApi.com
APP_ID=com.example.test
APP_NAME=App Dev
VERSION_CODE=1.0
VERSION_NAME=1
APP_ICON=ic_launcher
```

and in `app/build.gradle`'s defaultConfig:

```
...
applicationId project.env.get("APP_ID")
resValue "string", "app_name", project.env.get("APP_NAME")
versionCode project.env.get("VERSION_CODE").toInteger()
versionName project.env.get("VERSION_NAME")
```

I build the version correctly and display it on the device just fine, but then I run AppCenter's codepush commands and receive an error.

the command:

```
codepush release-react -a <my organization name here> -d Production
```

the error:

```
Error: Command 'codepush release-react -a <my organization name here> -d Production' failed with exception "No property named "env.get(VERSION_NAME)" exists in the "android/gradle.properties" file."
```

So, I assume Codepush cannot read the env value and the only way it works if I pass the `-t` flag with the version I want. The workaround would be to put `versionName` in the script for package.json file, but I wonder if it is possible for codepush to read the versionName from the env files correctly.

Comment: any solution for this question?

Comment: any solution for this issue?